# Word order for "whether" clause

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

I have this sentence:

> The main idea of the rule-based approaches is to judge each node of the DOM tree **whether it is** a text node **by its features**.

Should it be:

> The main idea of the rule-based approaches is to judge each node  of the DOM tree by its features **whether it is** a text node **or not**.

Update:

Or maybe

> The main idea of the rule-based approaches is to judge each node  of the DOM tree by its features **to see/check whether it is** a text node **or not**.

Comment: Neither is valid (you can't just stick the *whether* clause on the end like that). One valid alternative would be *The main idea of the rule-based approaches is to judge by its features **whether each node is a text node or not**.* That involves a "forward reference", which could be avoided with, say, *...to judge each node by its features **[in order] to ascertain** whether it is a text node or not*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, what about *The main idea of the rule-based approaches is to judge each node of the DOM tree by its features to see whether it is a text node or not.*

Comment: That sounds much better to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't agree. The OP's second is fine if it means: "... judge each node by its features regardless of whetherthat node is a text node or not."

Comment: @Araucaria thank you, but I didn't mean that, actually I am trying to use two adjuncts for "judge".

Comment: What happened to the DOM tree in the second sentence? We can't say which is better if the second sentence has parts missing. Could you either remove the DOM tree altogether, or have it in both sentences? Thanks.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK thank you for the point. it was missed.

Comment: @Araucaria: I can just about agree "at the margin", but I think that would be a somewhat dated/formal/poetic usage. In which case one might as well go the whole hog and include the subjunctive, ***whether it be grammatically required or no(t! :)***.

Answer (score 1):

> ... two adjuncts for *judge*...

**Judge** cannot take simultaneously both a direct object and an integrated whether-clause.

If the whether-clause is not integrated, then, yes, it can happen:

**It is not ours to judge a man — whether he have lust in his heart.**

With respect to forward references, they are not ungrammatical but they can be less than clear:

**The main purpose of these rules-based approaches is to judge, by *its* features, whether *each node* in the DOM tree is a text node.**